# How code written at global scope is used as the entry point for the program execution?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

It is mentioned that we need not to write main function in swift.

Rather in 'AppDelegate.swift' we have the below attribute.

```
@UIApplicationMain 
//Alternative for main function
```

or we need to import main.swift.

But how does playground works without importing any class or main function?
                             or how 
“Code written at global scope is used as the entry point for the program” in swift?

Comment: the statements in the playground are evaluated in order. what do you mean? the main function in swift is the statements that are written outside of a function or method.

Comment: I want to know about entry point of code execution without writing main function

Comment: What do you want to know about it?

Comment: I want to know what is the start point of code execution if main is not written as quoted in eBook for Swift.                            “Code written at global scope is used as the entry point for the program”.

Comment: I assume it's the first statement in your program at global scope. Did you try it to see?

Comment: @Priyanka,Did you get the answer for your question ?